# run npm scripts in kudu

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, aurelia, kudu

I've got a slick Aurelia app and now I want to publish to Azure using VSTS using continuous deployment. On deployment, I need to run a few node commands.

```
npm install
jspm install
npm run build:staging
```

How can I configure Kudu to run this?

Comment: I just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369323/610731. You can invoke npm via the Kudu API (using PowerShell or Bash for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From kudu's [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script#custom-deployment-script-generator):

Install `azure-cli`

```
npm install azure-cli -g
```

Switch azure console to asm mode

```
azure config mode asm
```

In your project's root, run the custom deployment script generator command:

```
azure site deploymentscript [options]
```

Now you can edit the deploy.cmd file and add your custom steps (like your npm commands).

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

... [deployment steps]

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: and this is better than just manually writing the .deployment file?