# How to run npm command on azure app service after deployment success by VSTS?

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, npm, azure-pipelines

Now I can deploy from VSTS to azure, but I can't run npm after deploy is successful.

Now it is work like -> run npm install for branch files => zip => copy to azure => deploy.

I want to add **npm run custom-comand** to end of this chain.
How to do it?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean about run npm command on Azure App Service?

Comment: I have node js app. I need to deploy it. So, I need to upload files from git and run few command like npm install or npm run server.

Comment: Usually, you need to run the npm install command during the build and then publish the build output include the installed node modules to Azure App Service. And I also see that you have already added a npm install step in your build definition. So why do you still need to run it on server?

Comment: how run node server command?

Comment: Also if npm install will be on server side we don't need send all files to server and it will be faster. now it is around 8minutes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **Azure App Service Deployment task** in VSTS now supports a post-deployment script. Here is a screen-shot from version 3.* of the task:

[image: Post Deployment Action settings]

See [Task Parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md#parameters-of-the-task) for more details.

**Windows App Services users**: Watch out for an [npm bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2938) that prevents multiple `npm` commands from being run (inline or in a script). For example:

```
npm install
npm test
```

Will only run `npm install`. There are several workarounds including [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2938#issuecomment-390927520):

```
npm install & npm test
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no out of box build task to achieve the feature you want. If you do want to run the npm from Azure App Service:

Manually: You can go to [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) of the App Service and run npm command there:[image]

Automatically: You need to create your own build task to run the npm command via [Kudu Rest API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)

Comment: while valid, this kind of kills the purpose of an automated deployment...

Answer (score 4):

You can run commands like `npm install` via the [Kudu REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API).

[Here's a scripted example written in PowerShell](https://github.com/DanielLarsenNZ/examples/blob/master/Scripts/Deploy/InvokeKuduNpmInstall.ps1).

Add a PowerShell script task after the **Azure App Service Deploy** task to invoke `npm install` (or any other command that Kudu supports). And disable the **npm install** task in your build pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

The Kudu deployment engine that App Service leverages has the ability to run custom deployment scripts.  You can include your desired npm command inside of a [custom deployment script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) that will be executed as part of the deployment on Azure's side. No REST API calls required and everything stays in your source control system.

Comment: I am so glad someone posted the correct answer. A custom deploy script is the only way this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PowerShell task** or **npm task** to execute npm commands .

One thing to note: you also need to upload the `.npmrc` with auth token to Azure.

Comment: What is .npmrc ?

Comment: Ok. .npmrc understand. But what is "auth token to Azure" and how add it to npmrc

Comment: When you execute `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth`, it will read your configured package source from the provided `.npmrc` file, and writes credentials to your user profile `.npmrc`. And you need to upload the `.npmrc` with credential to Azure, so that you can have authorization to execute npm commands on Azure. More detail about .npmrc and  credentials, you can refer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc.