# node.js deployed on Azure. No dependencies installed

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

According to Microsoft's own [documentaiton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps), dependencies should be installed when you deploy a node.js project to their web app service. Here I've simple used their own [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) and simple ran

```
npm i express
```

and added 1 single line in the index.js

```
const expres = require('express');
```

navigating to Kudu, there is no node_module folder. And indeed the app (which worked with the simple template) does not load. What am I missing?

[image: Result]

Comment: I'd add that after running npm install in the kudu console, the app started working. This is not ideal as part of a continuous integration plan... Thus, I'd like to find out how I can tell Azure during the deployment that it should install dependencies automatically (I override all files when I do a deployment)

Comment: seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379619/how-to-run-npm-command-on-azure-app-service-after-deployment-success-by-vsts/45369323) does not answer the question as to why it's not working but ensures that npm install runs anyway in VSTS deployment. 
I also should have mentioned I run this on a windows web app, not linux, where I'd have to configure it myself for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use [Zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#deploy-zip-file) mentioned in the tutorial, Kudu doesn't execute `npm install` as the zip file should contain everything in the app, including `node_modules`.

To make our modules installed during deployment, follow [local git deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git) or other [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment) like AzureDevOps(originally called VSTS).

For local git deployment,

1. Create a local git repository for our node web app.
2. Go to Azure portal, Deployment Centre> Pick Local Git> Pick Kudu build server(or AzureDevOps, they both handle the build process automatically)> Finish. Note the `Git Clone Uri` to use later.
3. Open powershell in local app dir, input `git remote add azure <Git Uri noted before>` and `git push azure master`. App will be deployed and modules will be installed according to 
   `dependencies` in `package.json`.